# how can i pass a parameter in a thread in ansi c windows lib can also be used?

Tags: c, winapi

```
            int NM_Generator = 1; 

            //Aray to store thread handles 
            HANDLE Array_Of_Thread_Handles[1];

            //variable to hold handle of North pulse
            HANDLE Handle_Of_NM_Generator = 0; 

            //Create NM_Generator Thread
            Handle_Of_NM_Generator = CreateThread( NULL, 0, NMGenerator, &dDifference, 0, NULL);  
            if ( Handle_Of_NM_Generator == NULL)   ExitProcess(NM_Generator);
```

i want to pass a parameter  double value in it how can i do so?

Comment: ANSI C does not have threads.

Comment: what threading library is it?

Comment: @Stephen: CreateThread is a Win32 API (as is ExitProcess), and HANDLE is a common type in Win32. I'm gonna go with Win32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i find it

```
        //Create NM_Generator Thread
        Handle_Of_NM_Generator = CreateThread( NULL, 0, NMGenerator, &dDifference, 0, NULL);  
        if ( Handle_Of_NM_Generator == NULL)   ExitProcess(NM_Generator); 


 //dDifference is the thread parameter
```

Answer (score 2):

CreateThread allows you to pass in a single parameter of type `void *` and the thread procedure is called with the parameter.

If you want to pass an argument of type T where `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void *)`, you can simply cast your argument to a `void *` in the call to `CreateThread` and cast it back to your type in your thread procedure.

But if `sizeof(T) > sizeof(void *)` you are going to need to create a structure that will hold your arguments.  You will then pass a pointer to the `CreateThread` call (as a `void *`).

When passing a pointer to a structure, you will need to make sure it has an appropriate lifetime.  The easiest way to do this is by allocating the structure on the heap before calling `CreateThread` and then freeing the memory inside your thread procedure.

Answer (score 1):

You are already passing the parameter with "&dDifference".

Check this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682516(v=VS.85).aspx) on how to create a thread.